# Android image sharpen based on range

Tags: java, android, image-processing, graphic

I need to sharpen an android image based on range, eg 1~100.

And I know using a matrix convolution to get sharpened result.

But how can I do sharpen image by using seekbar to adjust the sharpeness.

For example, "1" is less sharpen, "100" is most sharpen.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out : https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-sharpening-image/

Comment: Thank to  @HareshChhelana.  But if I set weight to 100, the sharpen result didn't make big change than setting weight to 1. So I use interative method, here is it "for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { bm = sharpen(bm, 9);}" , then it produce a most effect result. However, if I set "i<5", the result image is lose its color.

Comment: Please post another question to SO for farther query.

Comment: If the matrix sharpness result is good enough to be called "100" then simply put a copy of the original in a layer above the now sharp image and your slider (or seekbar) can simply control alpha of top layer (more sharpness = less visiblity of original = more visibility of sharper image). Just a simple idea that may be ok for you...

Comment: Thank to @VC.One. But can you tell me  the detail of alpha?

Comment: @HareshChhelana it is very time-consuming means it is not smoothly working. any other idea ?